# Git workflow without SSH or HTTPS access

Tags: git, https, ssh, github, workflow

I need to work on someone's dev(unused webhost) server to build their website on... The servers are not SSH enabled and because it's shared hosting the company won't let me edit the Apache configuration which would allow me to work with git through HTTPS...
My question is, since I cannot use git directly with the dev server, is it worth using locally and have two different locations of the website?
For example... normally you would connect to your dev server and work on that, every time you commit/push it goes right to the Dev server. In my case, it doesn't go anywhere besides a private Github repo, because there's not way I can use git with the dev server.
What would you guys do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use `git` on the server, then you can still copy files from your git repo the ordinary way.  You probably don't really need the entire `git` repo on the server anyway, just an up-to-date working copy.

Use `rsync` to copy files directly from a clean local repository to the target server.  Make sure to exclude `.git` from the `rsync` operation.

If you don't have `rsync`, use `sftp`.

If you don't have `sftp`, then... something is seriously wrong.

Comment: I have sftp plugin for sublime text 2, which is what I always use anyways... I was hoping I could just make it so the github repo syncs to the server rather than my local files

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "github repo syncs to the server".  Could you elaborate?  Normally, you push or pull between two repos (and github is just another repo).

Comment: Or, to put it another way: Git only lets you copy between computers that have git running on them.  If you can't run git on the server, you can't use git to put files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

For now use git for version control, and just re-copy all files everytime you need to update the code (or at least the files that have changed).

If the server has shell access (maybe a script can run shell commands), then you can create a script to do this (perhaps this can be done everytime you visit a webpage):

```
git pull
```

for you. This of course depends on git having been installed on the server. If not, find a portable git installation, and keep that git folder on your webserver.

If not all commits on the master branch will be fast-forward, you might need:

```
git pull --force
```

or similar.

And if it runs the script whenever you access it, you can try using .htaccess to require a username password to git pull.